# File structure for Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, windows-10

I am currently learning Node.js and MongoDB for an open source project.

**How should they be located in relation to one another as far as their source files?**

MongoDB defaults the data folder to root, but I have MongoDB itself installed in a sub directory. Node.js in installed in yet another sub directory on same drive.

**Do they need to be located in same location, or does that not matter?**

Thanks for any clarification, didn't see this anywhere in the tutorials I am learning from.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but if you're just learning how to use the two together you might want to use a cloud based mongo provider like MongoLab - perhaps a tutorial like this might help - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/detailed-introduction-nodejs-mongodb/

Comment: No does not matter, you need to connect to MongoDB via connection string so path does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It doesn't matter.

When you use the mongo client to connect to the mongoDB server, you already specified a host & port of that mongodb instance (this is what matters).

To use mongoDB in nodeJS: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/.

Hope it helps

Comment: I got it running, and it didn't matter. Thanks, just wanted to make sure before I started installing everything.